# Can I deactivate a PS3 I can no longer use?

Tags: ps3

I have an old PS3 that no longer boots (yellow light of death). I haven't yet reached my limit of activated PSN devices (as I understand there's a limit to how many places you can download content).

Can I deactivate this device remotely? Similar services like Amazon MP3/Kindle let me remote access remotely. Can I do that? Does it matter for the number of activated devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to deactivate all devices

Log-in to your PSN account at https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.action
Click on the Account tab on the top of the screen and then choose Media and Devices on the left side.
Four boxes will appear on the right: one for Video, Game, Music and Comics. Click on the V symbol in the Game box and then choose Deactivate All.
Click Yes to confirm deactivation.

Comment: Just to add to Dan's correct answer, you'll have to manually activate your other PS devices again to play purchased contents on them. Just know that this remote deactivation is only possible once every six months.

Comment: Deactivating won't remove/disable any data on my active devices once I reactivate them, will it?